# Designing a Python string validation library

Tags: python, libraries, regular-expressions

My employer has a significant number of company-internal strings which require format validation. For instance, order number `AAA-BBB-CCC`, stock number `AB-123456` or factory `ABC1` - Regex with extras (think checksum, number range).

Having re-implemented functions for every project I have been on, I wanted to publish a robust internal library for the common ones.

I have an idea of each string validation being a class (Factory design pattern):

```py
from company_regex import OrderNumber, StockNumber, FactoryCode

OrderNumber("AAA-BBB-CCC") 
StockNumber("AB-123456")
FactoryCode("ABC1")
```

**I am unsure of some architecture/design considerations:**

Q1. Is it more pythonic to infer validation on instancing the class, or should I explicitly call it? There is little value in having an invalid object, but I am not sure about inferring actions.

```py
OrderNumber("AAA-BBB-CCC")  #  with validate_format() called through __init__()
OrderNumber("AAA-BBB-CCC").validate_format()
```

Q2. From an architecture perspective, I am not sure if I should be (a) be raising exceptions or (b) return `False` when validation fails?

```py
OrderNumber("AAA-BBB-C") #  raise exception
OrderNumber("AAA-BBB-C") #  return false
OrderNumber("AAA-BBB-C", errors='raise') #  could make it flexible but more complex
```

For Option A:

```py
try:
    order = OrderNumber("AAA-BBB-C")
except:
    print("Format incorrect")
```

vs. Option B:

```py
order_number = OrderNumber("AAA-BBB-C")

if order_number is False:
    print("Format incorrect")
```

Q3. There is a frequent need to validate a list or Pandas series. I can check the input type on instantiation - but I fear including this in the library will make it messy. Should I consider including this functionality or leave leave this to the application/code using it?

```
OrderNumber("AAA-BBB-CCC")
OrderNumber(["AAA-BBB-CCC", "AAA-BBB-DDD"])
OrderNumber(pd.Series(["AAA-BBB-CCC", "AAA-BBB-DDD"]))
```

Comment: Instance method `__init__` should either raise an exception if it tries to construct a correct `OrderNumber` object and fails, or set an internal boolean flag; but a class method `OrderNumber.validate_format` can return a boolean without constructing a new object. Which one of these three (non-exclusive) alternatives is better depends on your usecases.

Comment: Calling a class shouldn't return `False` if validation fails. Indeed, I don't think it _can_. Surely `ClassName(*args, **kwargs)` can only return - without `__init__` using that keyword - an instance of said class.

Comment: @J.G. "The `__new__` method is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be unnatural." But I totally agree that if OP should want that behaviour, it would be clearer to define a function than a class.

Comment: @amon Thanks for reminding me of how powerful `__new__` can be. Of course, defining a function doesn't mean it needs a long name, all thanks to `__call__`.

Comment: One thing you should consider is what your requirements are around invalid data.  For example, if there is a requirement to record orders with invalid data and process them on an alternate requirements path, you might want to allow the OrderNumber to be created even if the number is invalid.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keep it simple. Either offer *functions* that check or assert the format, or create a *type* that represents a validated string. These approaches have different tradeoffs.

The most generic approach may be to create functions that return a boolean.

```py
def is_order_number(raw: str) -> bool: ...

if not is_order_number(some_input):
  print("Format incorrect")
```

However, this can lead to repetitive code at call sites.

Depending on the usage patterns, it may be better to offer a function that raises an exception when the input is invalid. This function could be implemented in terms of that previous check:

```py
def assert_is_order_number(raw: str):
  if not is_order_number:
    raise ValueError(f"OrderNumber must have format AAA-BBB-CCC, but got {raw!r}")

def some_function(order):
  assert_is_order_number(order)
  ...
```

Such assertion functions may be appropriate in particular if you have lots of checks at the beginning of functions, and all you'd ever do with invalid data is to raise an exception.

Using a class for validation offers additional opportunities. We can use this class to describe already-validated strings, but that means that the constructor must run the validation logic.

If you use a static type checker such as MyPy, this lets you ensure that functions get already-validated data, without having to re-check the format themselves. Thus, this can even improve performance (a tiny bit). For example:

```py
class OrderNumber(str):
  def __init__(self, raw: str) -> None:
    assert_is_order_number(raw)
    super().__init__(raw)

def some_function(order: OrderNumber):
  ...  # no check needed here
```

It's actually not necessary to create a custom class here. If you only want to use `OrderNumber` for static type checking, but don't want the ability to check `instanceof(..., OrderNumber)`, then a simpler design could involve `NewType` from the `typing` module. However, that would make it impossible to guarantee that the order number format had actually been checked.

You suggested one solution that I'm really not excited about: offering a class that requires an additional method to be invoked for validation: `OrderNumber("AAA-BBB-CCC").validate_format()`

The problem here is that it's not at all apparent that `validate_format()` must be called. Unless you have very good test coverage, you might forget to call that check. The `OrderNumber("AAA-BBB-CCC")` call alone looks like it might already be doing something (and indeed you have suggested designs where this is the case).

You raise the question which design would be most "pythonic". There is no definite answer here, and the matter can be answered either way. I'd tend to suggest that using exceptions is preferable, since they can't be ignored accidentally. I'd also prefer plain functions over classes, since they're easier to implement and can be used more flexibly – unless you actually need a class, for example to enable static type checking.

If you frequently need validation on Pandas data-series, that could be a good argument to include it in your validation library. On the other hand, this would mean that every user of your library would indirectly depend on Pandas, which may be undesirable. In any case, a user can easily use a loop or list comprehension to check all items in a list or series. For example:

```py
assert all(is_order_number(n) for n in my_unvalidated_data), \
  "All input items must be a valid order number (AAA-BBB-CCC)"
```

If you have this kind of pattern frequently, it could be appropriate to create an abstraction:

```py
assert_multiple(
  a_description: str,
  is_valid: Callable[[str], bool],
  items: Iterable[str],
):
  for item in items:
    if not is_valid(item):
      raise ValueError(f"All items must be {a_description}, but got {item!r}")

assert_multiple(
  "a valid order number (AAA-BBB-CCC)",
  is_order_number,
  my_unvalidated_data,
)
```

Comment: I agree functions are the way to go, and why not provide both the bool `is_valid_foo(s:str)` and throwing `check_valid_foo` variants.  I would suggest throwing a subclass like `MyValidationError` though to distinguish from value errors produced by external libraries etc.

Comment: I don't know whether it's pythonic but in order to avoid an exception when instantiating the class, you can have a function that either returns OrderNumber or None.

Answer (score 15):

I am under the impression you are looking too much from the implementation side at your lib. Try to look at it from the **calling side** and ask yourself

*"How would you like to use your library?"*

Since your requirements are coming from some existing projects, it shouldn't be too hard to find some real use cases to verify your design choices, whatever they are.

Said that, some thoughts of mine (which are surely debatable):

- When the only thing you can get back from a validation is a "true" or "false", throwing an exception is IMHO overdesigned, and a boolean function should be sufficient. And if your lib is used in different contexts, a failing validation might be a regular situation, nothing which is necessarily exceptional. Hence I personally would prefer a boolean test function for this case. But as I wrote above, verify this choice by looking at your older projects and think how you would prefer the lib to be used there.
- If you validate a list of values, you usually want to know which of the elements of the list passs the validation and which not. Keep that in mind when making a choice for Q3. When you create a function which only returns "true" or "false" for a single value, and then afterwards extend it to also accept multiple values, you might confuse users by making the function then return a list of booleans.

  However, in case you are really requiring this functionality very often, making a second method `ValidateOrderNumbers` which returns a list of results (with one element per input element) could make sense. Of course, you should avoid a dependency of your lib on 3rd party libs like Pandas, but that should not be too hard in Python, by implementing this generically in terms of iterators.

Comment: *"Of course, you should avoid a dependency of your lib on 3rd party libs like Pandas"* I think in python it should be possible to write a function that manipulates pandas objects, using their methods and attributes, without importing pandas? And the caller will only by able to call them on pandas objects if they already have pandas objects, which means they imported pandas? I don't know whether that's good practice.

Comment: @Stef: the task here is not to "manipulate pandas objects", the task is to validate a list of strings. Implementing a generic validating function which just takes an arbitrary iterator, retrieves the items from that iterator, validates them and returns the result as an iterator by itself is pretty standard.

Comment: “ And if your lib is used in different contexts, a failing validation might be a regular situation, nothing which is necessarily exceptional”. I think a lot of Python users might disagree on that point. A lot of python code uses exception as control flow where its not as expensive as say cpp or java to use. Try/except on converting str to int is often the easiest way to tell if a string has an int form, or how errors are used to indicate the end of an iterator when using ’next’. Like you said, it depends on the usecase, but exceptions do not need to be exceptional :)

Comment: @flakes: using exceptions only for "exceptional" situations is not only or primarily a question of "beeing expensive"  - it is also a question of readability and ease-of-use. When a validation function does only return true or false, I see no reason to *force* a user into using exceptions for control flow, expensive or not.

Comment: @DocBrown Agreed its not just about cost, but I do prefer it over other options, like Golang returning multiple values, e.g. `val, err := func(); if err: ...`, or sentinel value like `-1` to represent errors from a lot of C functions. For this case, there are two states, fail or succeed, which can fit nicely into a boolean. Once you need complex/awkward response types to handle errors without raising, I start disliking it. Even here, I'd argue the error raised could have a message about why it failed, which a boolean state would lack (and a string response would feel less idiomatic).